# how to use the like operator to filter a stored procedure in sql

Tags: sql-server

Table 1

### Number

> 924-852132-200
>
> 927-856985-200

table 2

### Digits

> 927-856985-100
>
> 927-12360-400

```
select count(Number)
from table 1 inner join table 2 on Number=digits
```

so if i enter 927-856985-200 it must match it on the digits table. but the digits column only has the last 3 digits of 100 and the number table has the last 3 digits of 200 however the ten digits infront of it is the same, so the expected output would be a count of 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to achieve the above it would be

> select count(number)  from table1 inner join table 2 on
>   substring(number,0,12)=substring(digits,0,12)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)

```
select left(guid_column, 10)   
from your_table
```

Comment: i tried that,it doesnt work, i need to use it in my where clause because i have other inner joins on the Number column

Comment: What does *not work* mean? Can you add your query and explain what you want to do? Edit your question please.

Comment: so whats happening is that because its coming in like 927-856985-200 and table two doesnt have that it cant count that number so it comes back as zero